# create unique record data frame where multiple records of each applicant present

Tags: r, dataframe, if-statement, cbind

"I have one data frame in which bank related information of each applicant id is present. suppose applicants has multiple account and data frame reflects this information in multiple rows. Now I want to create a data frame in which each applicant all information is in one record"

I have tried it with for and if loop. Now I want to optimised code

```
com_data <- function(X) {
  data_set <- data.frame(table(X$id))
  a <- 3
  n <- 3
  for (i in 1:nrow(data_set)) {
    for (j in 1:nrow(X[1:4])) {
      if (data_set$Var1[i] == X$id[j]) {
        count <- count + 1
        #k <- j
      }
      if (count == 1) {
        for (k in 3:ncol(X))

          data_set[i, n] <- X[j, k]
        n <- n + 1

      } else{
        for (k in 3:ncol(X))

          data_set[i, n] <- X[j, k]
        n <- n + 1

      }
    }
    count = 0
    n <- 3

  }

  return(data_set)
}
```

Comment: Your code could use some mock data to demonstrate the problem.

Answer (score 0):

Gets a little messy assumes your dataframe isn't comprised of list vectors. "Var" should be applicant id:

```
# Sample data used: 

df <- data.frame(

  Date = as.Date(c("27/9/2019", "28/9/2019", "1/10/2019", "2/10/2019"), "%d/%m/%y"),

  dateTime = as.POSIXct(c("27/9/2019", "28/9/2019", "1/10/2019", "2/10/2019"), "%d/%m/%y %H:M:S"),

  Var = as.factor(c("A", "A", "B", "B")), 

  Value = c(56, 50, 90, 100),

  stringsAsFactors = F
)


# Convert factors & dates to strings: 

convert_descriptors_to_char <- function(df){

  as.data.frame(lapply(df, 
                       function(x){

                         if(is.factor(x) | inherits(x, "Date") | inherits(x, "POSIXct") | inherits(x, "POSIXlt")) { 

                           as.character(trimws(x, which = "both"))

                         } else{ 

                           x

                         }

                       }

  ),

  stringsAsFactors = FALSE) 

}

# Convert data types: 

df <- convert_descriptors_to_char(df)

# Merge the separate lists into one: 

df_aggd <- lapply(df, function(x){

                           if(is.character(x)){

                           aggregate(x~df$Var, df, paste0, collapse = ", ")

                           }else if(is.numeric(x)){

                            aggregate(x~df$Var, df, sum) 

                           }else{

                             x

                           }

                         }

                  )

    # Vector to rename "x" to:

    x_vect_names <- names(sapply(df_aggd, function(x){deparse(substitute(x))}))

    # Iterate through list to rename: 

    for (i in seq_along(df_aggd)){

      colnames(df_aggd[[i]]) <- c("Var", x_vect_names[i])

    }

    # Remove Var df: 

    df_aggd <- df_aggd[names(df_aggd) != "Var"]

    # Merge the separate dataframes into one:

    Reduce(function(x, y){merge(x, y, all = TRUE, by = intersect(colnames(x), colnames(y)))}, df_aggd)
```

Comment: You should post an anonymised version of your dataset then. This code is generic and will run if you change the variable names appropriately.

Comment: Thanks for your reply but in my code when I find unique var it will automatically append the record corresponding and get the output  is in dataframe format

Comment: It's very hard to tell what your code is doing because you haven't posted your data. Also the above code also outputs a dataframe.

Comment: try this if you want everything in a single record as a string:
df <- data.frame(lapply(df, as.character), stringsAsFactors = FALSE)
stacked_df <- aggregate(.~id, df, paste0, collapse = ", ")